# Windows 10 Virtual Box having windows installed on driver

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on my Laptop. Due to work reasons, I want to use Windows while working on Ubuntu (in order not to keep on switching). So I installed virtual box and what I would like to know now, is whether installing windows on the virtual box would cause any problems like losing my data installed on the real windows or would cause any harm to it.

If no, please also specify if any password is required for the virtual windows. If yes, then is it similar to the one i already have on the real one or should I get a new one to make it work?

Thank You for your help, and if any further information is needed please ask.

Comment: When/if you create a new virtual machine and install Windows on it, it will be completely separate from the physically installed Windows on your laptop.  You need to think of the VM as a separate physical computer.  Now, if you're trying to run your existing Windows under VirtualBox, then that is a different scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
and so what i understand "real" windows doesn't get affected, but do you think i can use the same license I have for the virtual one?

Comment: You can't install the license in the VM and keep it on your host. It's limited to one install for retail versions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not familiar with the concept of virtualization I'll try not to use technical language or explain thousands of possible configurations.

> I would like to know now, is whether installing windows on the virtual
>   box would cause any problems like losing my data installed on the real
>   windows or would cause any harm to it.

A virtual machine is nothing but a bunch of files that VirtualBox (or other virtualization product like Vmware Workstation) creates in a folder that you're gonna specify during creation along with other settings. All that happens while logged in on the VM is contained to the files and won't affect the host of the VM.

You can even configure the VM not to have any kind of external access by removing its network interface and prohibiting file transfer from host to VM if you wish.

> please also specify if any password is required for the virtual
>   windows. If yes, then is it similar to the one i already have on the real one or should I get a new one to make it work?

Once you create a virtual machine it's like the VM doesn't know about being a VM, so you configure it completely apart from your host. The OS inside the VM doesn't Know it's runnig inside another OS and will need user/password just like any Windows you install on your Desktop, therefore any user you create on the host won't exist on the VM and vice versa.